# Passing certificate and key file using C#

Tags: c#, ssl

We have new process where we need to use certificate file and private key file for web authentication.

Files:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----  
MIIFtjj.......k=  
-----END CERTIFICATE-----  

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----  
MIIEow.......jsTC9bx  
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Examples are given for python and curl that work fine:

```
curl -s -k --key ./my.key --cert ./my.cert https://[domain]/[endpoint]/[id_number]/

requests.get(url, cert=(CERT_FILE, KEY_FILE), verify=False)
```

That works fine for linux environments, we are also responsible for some Windows applications, where we need to access the service.

the cert files were created using "openssl"
openssl x509 -inform pem -in certificate.pem > my.cert
openssl rsa -in key.pem > my.key

Installing the certifcates to the windows machines is not an option since we may not have that level of access to the box.

I have tried:

```
ServicePointManager.CheckCertificateRevocationList = false;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ( a, b, c, d ) => true;
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 9999;

var certificate = new X509Certificate2( CERT_FILE );
byte[] buffer = Helpers.DecodeOpenSslPrivateKey( keyfile );  // reads in the rsa file minus the start end tags and converts from base64
certificate.PrivateKey = Helpers.DecodeRsaPrivateKey( buffer );
// similiar to: https://github.com/StefH/OpenSSL-X509Certificate2-Provider/blob/master/src/OpenSSL.PrivateKeyDecoder/OpenSSLPrivateKeyDecoder.cs

HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create( url ) as HttpWebRequest;
request.PreAuthenticate = true;
request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
request.ClientCertificates.Add( certificate );

WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
// fails here with: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel
```

There are a lot of places where people suggest converting the keys to pkcs12 or some other openssl export, but these keys work as is from the same machine using CURL or python.  The CURL shows the connection over TLS12, and I am running .Net 4.51 (upgrading to 4.6 is not an option)

Comment: You load the certificate from disk, but where are you using it afterwards?